# picture-urls::(original) and summary fields no longer returned by API

Tags: linkedin-api

As per Lorrie Corman's answer [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/590306):

> you can submit any questions you have to the 'Stack Overflow'. Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure to tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them

Well, either LinkedIn engineers do not exist, or they don't see the #linkedin tag.

In any case, thousands of websites are broken now because LinkedIn changed their API without caring to notify anyone.

`picture-urls::(original)` and `summary` fields have been missing from API results for several weeks now, and still no sign of an official LinkedIn answer anywhere.

What should developers relying on these values do? @LinkedIn, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that too, the only picture we can use now is `picture-url` which is is quite small. 100x100.

I'm still waiting for a response from them as well, because there is nothing on the documentation about this.

Comment: LinkedIn support answered me and told me that they don't offer support for the API. We are alone in the dark on this one.

Comment: That's crazy! They removed something really useful without telling anyone or planning to add it anytime soon...